# Как сделать анимацию движения объекта по кривой (алгоритм Безье)

Tags: python, анимация, tkinter, ffmpeg, anaconda

Вот что имею на данный момент, вроде всё хорошо работает, но хотелось бы комментарий к каждой строке кода, а также, как убрать маркер и вместо него заставить двигаться эллипс, диаметр, длину ширину, которого, можно будет менять.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera
import numpy as np
 
tau=np.linspace(0,1,1000)
P=np.array([[180, 290],
           [140, 335],
           [50,  170],
           [10,   15],
           [360, 240],
           [140,  67]
           ])
 
def Bezier(t, P):
    # Bezier Matrix:
    Mb=np.matrix([
        [ -1,   5, -10,  10, -5, 1],
        [  5, -20,  30, -20,  5, 0],
        [-10,  30, -30,  10,  0, 0],
        [ 10, -20,  10,   0,  0, 0],
        [ -5,   5,   0,   0,  0, 0],
        [  1,   0,   0,   0,  0, 0]
                 ])
    # T matrix
    xx, yy=np.meshgrid(np.arange(5, -1, -1), t)
    xx=np.matrix(xx)
    yy=np.matrix(yy)
    T_mat=np.power(yy, xx)
    B=T_mat*Mb*P
    return B
%matplotlib qt5
fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0,600)
plt.ylim(0,600)
X,Y=Bezier(tau, P)[:,0],Bezier(tau, P)[:,1]
camera = Camera(fig)
 
for i in range(100):
    coord=Bezier(i/100, P)
    plt.plot(X,Y,color = '#ff0000')
    plt.scatter(coord[0,0], coord[0,1], color = '#00ff00' , marker='o')
    camera.snap()
    
animation = camera.animate(interval = 200, repeat = True,
                           repeat_delay = 500)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

tau это одномерный массив состоящий из 1000 элементов от 0 до 1?

P это двумерный массив, где хранятся координаты x,y моих контрольных точек.

Mb это двумерный массив, где хранятся коэффициенты при t,
Затем создаём прямоугольную сетку используя одномерные массивы xx и yy (от -5 до -1 с шагом -1), и зачем нужен параметр t здесь? не понял 25 строку.

xx = матрица размерностью хх

yy = матрица размерностью yy

(    T_mat=np.power(yy, xx)) снова не понял, но это возведение элемента массива yy в степень элемента массива xx?

Затем создаём объект figure без осей

Затем устанавливаем пределы x и y осей

(X,Y=Bezier(tau, P)[:,0],Bezier(tau, P)[:,1]) не понял что происходит, но что-то присваивается переменным x и y

Затем в цикле получаем координаты точек, отображаем их на графике красным цветом
Добавляем маркер зелёного цвета (что значит coord[0,0], coord[0,1]?)

Затем снимок камеры

После того, как все кадры были получены, создаём анимацию?

Answer (score 0):

Анимированные графики на Python создаются с помощью функции FuncAnimation из модуля animation библиотеки matplotlib.

Документация: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html

Примеры:
https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/animation/simple_anim.html

Тюториал:
https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

Comment: Не хочу делать поспешных выводов, но разве не нужно в ответе писать основную мысль, того что находимся по ссылкам?

Comment: По ссылкам находиться описание того, как анимировать график. Можно конечно свой ответ строить на изложении хорошо структурированного текста в укороченном и адаптированном для школьников виде и своими словами. Вот только зачем. Если человеку реально нужно решить свою проблему, то он пройдет по ссылкам, прочтёт, разберется и  использует его для решения. А если ему просто лень, и хочется "на все готовенькое" - ну тогда да, только готовое решение. Потом правда удивляются - а почему это входит в привычку и люди вообще перестают самостоятельно думать. Но - это не наша проблема. Или все-таки наша?

Comment: Не я имею в виду не скидывать просто готовый код, а расписать идею основную по типу: чтобы сделать график используйте такие то функции и т.д. Просто на ruSO даже предложение за которое удаляют ответ есть: "Спам-ссылка (не помню что тут)" и далее расписывается, что лучше писать с сайта основную информацию, чтобы если ссылка станет не действительной, чтобы пользователи смогли основную информацию получить. Я думаю это логично делать.

Comment: @passant , Анимация почему-то работает, только если добавить строчку %matplotlib qt, а затем удалить её, если просто скопировать код и запустить, отображается просто координатная плоскость без линии и анимации.
Запускаю этот код https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/animation-in-python-celluloid (Example Implementation of Animation in Python)
Всё работает, перезагружаю kernel, всё работает, анимация показывается, вставляю код из примера,анимация работает, перезагружаю kernel снова просто координатная плоскость, иначе говоря, если в новый файл вставить код примера, он не работает, почему?

Comment: @Павел Ериков "расписать идею основную по типу: чтобы сделать график используйте такие то функции и т.д." -  в приведенных мною ссылках есть тьюторил. Страниц на 5  или 7. Где подробно, с примером расписано и объяснено что и как надо делать. Вы предлагаете это перевести на русский и разместить на форуме? Впрочем, если хотите - можете этим заняться.  И что-то мне кажется, что ссылка на документацию по функции станет недоступной тогда, когда эта функция утратит свою актуальность. Думаю, это будет нескоро.

Comment: @passant  да господи у вас 5к репутации неужели вы не понимаете о чем я говорю? На сайте есть причина за которую закрыть могут ответ, как раз связанную с тем, что человек просто выкладывает одни ссылки. И расписано, что если ссылка станет не действительной, то основная часть ответа сохранится. Я не прошу вас все переводить и все переписывать. Я просто говорю, что почему не выписать прям основу основу. Чтобы люди у которых возникнет такая же проблема, могли увидеть эту основу и дальше идти по ссылка, если они конечно действительны будут. Ладно вы не понимаете меня, так что давайте прекратим.

Comment: @Shadow_fiend Ваша ссылка на какой-то код, который использует какие-то совершенно стронние библиотеки. Я допускаю, что они корректны и работают как надо. Но разбираться в них особого желания нет. Тем более, что есть прямой и понятный, "одобренный свыше" и многократно проверенный путь сотворения анимационных изображений, ссылки на которые я вам дал.  Но пользоваться ими или идти другим путем - ваш выбор.

Comment: @Павел Ериков -  да потому-что в условиях карантина и он-лайн обучения мне уже пришлось  в таком эпистолярном жанре объяснять дипломникам, как сделать анимацию. Это заняло две с половиной страницы текста плюс примеры кода еще на две страницы.  Меньше - просто безсмысленно. Форум -  это не место, где находят новую информацию. Форум - это место, где ищут ответ,  уточняют и разъясняют для себя конкретный вопрос.  Или - получают толчок - ссылку в том направлении, где можно найти подробное изложение темы. Мне так кажется.

Comment: @passant если у вас были похожие ответы, то просто скидывайте ссылку на вопрос, где вы один раз подробно ответили и все. Ну да тут находят ответ, но просто ГИПОТЕТИЧЕСКИ представьте если ваши ссылки станут не действительны. А у меня возник вопрос, как сделать анимацию и я нашел данный вопрос и вижу ответ ссылками вообще без какой либо, хотя бы маленькой информации. И что мне делать? Новый вопрос задавать чтобы вы ответили ссылками новыми? И почему вы все преувеличиваете? Зачем 2 страницы писать. Напиши основу по типу, вот функция она анимирует и потом "поподробней можете почитать тут" и ссылки

Comment: @Павел Ериков  -  чем ваше предложение "Напиши основу по типу, вот функция она анимирует и потом "поподробней можете почитать тут" и ссылки" отличатеся от того, что я написал "Анимированные графики на Python создаются с помощью функции FuncAnimation из модуля animation библиотеки matplotlib." и дал необходимые ссылки?

Comment: @passant не знаю я лично смотрю и вижу просто `FuncAnimation` как будто название функции вы придумали. Вы могли бы написать, что конкретно она делает, что принимает. Если эта функция такая важная, то почему бы не написать о ней что нибудь?

Comment: @Shadow_fiend Ваше коррекция вопроса после 14 часов его обсуждения -  меняет сам вопрос. Тем не менее - ответ на него остается тем-же ""Анимированные графики на Python создаются с помощью функции FuncAnimation из модуля animation библиотеки matplotlib." И да, название функции -  как и саму функцию -  увы, придумал не я.

Comment: @passant За ссылки спасибо, почитал, что-то стало понятнее, общими силами получился вышенаписанный код, но некоторые моменты не понимаю, а нужно закомментировать каждую строчку.